# How to add Project to use everywhere without changing anything in another project

Tags: java, android, packaging, android-package-managers

I really apologize, if this question has been answered earlier, I haven't found any appropriate answer so I am asking this one.

I have developed an android application. Now I want to develop same application with different splash screen and logo. So I want to use my earlier project for development so that if some changes happen in logic I can track them easily.

What i am trying to do is that `add this project and use the project as library every where`.

(**Project 1** -> Parent project which I want to use as library)

(**Project 2** -> Child project where I want to use the parent project)
I went to ***Project 2*** (where I want to add/use parent project as library)
`project properties -> Java Build Path -> Project  -> Add` then added the ***Project1*** (parent project)

Now in MainActivity of the ***Project2*** (child project) where I am using the ***Project1***

**MainActivity:**

```
package child.project.appStar;
 public class MainActivity extends parent.project.appStar.MainActivity {

 }
```

Now is there anything else that I need to add or can I simply run this project in my devices?

#### Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the main project as library project. IF you using eclipse open the main project project.properties file and add this :

```
 android.library=true
 manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

And don't add any main/launcher intent in any activity of manifest.xml file.

Child/Sub project add these lines on the project.properties file.  "*../MainProject*" is the path of ur main project and "*MainProject*" is the project name. {make sure these are correct.}

```
 android.library.reference.1=../MainProject
 manifestmerger.enabled=true
 android.library=false
```

Then at sub project you just need to import the main project files .. and u can access them.

```
 import com.MainProject.myActivity;

 public class MainActivity extends myActivity{ }
```

Comment: could you explain this And don't add any launcher point in manifest.xml file. ??

Comment: I mean donot add following in any activity.
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: its the default one you want me to remove these lines from Manifest file??

Comment: yes at the Library project we don't need it launching part is take care by sub project.

Comment: here i am pasting my child project Manifest file please have a look on this and tell me what need to be done?  
target=android-19
Parent Properties file:

target=android-16
android.library=true
android.library.reference.1=../../Download Sample Projects/HorizontalVariableListView/HorizontalVariableListView-master/library
android.library.reference.1=../MainProject
manifestmerger.enabled=true

Comment: please have a look on my edited section of the question.

Comment: See as i explain in ans MainProject is the name of project.. its not android keyword. so remove this android.library.reference.1=../MainProject And what is you main project name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49376/discussion-between-neha-and-rup35h)